# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException al separar una palabra ingresada por consola

Tags: java, array

Por  mas que he intentado identificar el error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

y no he podido encontrarlo. Mi codigo es :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise31 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter year: ");
        String year = input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter gender: ");
        String gender = input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String name = input.next();
        input.close();

        File file = new File("babynameranking" + year + ".txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("No record for " + year);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int rank = 0;
        try {
            Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
            while (read.hasNext()) {

                String s = read.nextLine();
                String[] temp = s.split(" ");

                if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && temp[1].contains(name))
                    rank = new Integer(temp[0]);
                else if (temp[3].contains(name)) // aqui me marca el error 
                    rank = new Integer(temp[0]);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (rank == 0) {
            System.out.println("The name "+name+" is not ranked in year " + year);
        } else {

            System.out.println(name+" is ranked #"+rank+" in year "+ year);
        }


    }
}
```

`babynameranking<AÑO>.txt` son diez archivos con el mismo nombre pero con diferente `AÑO` del 2001 al 2010 en los cuales hay listas de nombres de mujeres y hombres enumerados según el ranking de popularidad en cada `AÑO` entonces tengo que hacer que cuando yo entre el `AÑO` , el sexo y el nombre me muestre el numero del ranking.

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por otro lado no indicas que datos estas usando o que linea especifica es el problema.

Comment: ¿En cuál línea te marca el error?

Comment: Hay varios detalles que son importantes, como el contenido del archivo "babynameranking<AÑO>.txt" que no especificas.

Answer (score 2):

Para que entiendas porque sucede tu error primero un poco de información.

Cuando usas el método [split()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45846/c%C3%B3mo-separar-un-string-en-java-c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-split) en java obtienes un array, como ejemplo:

```
 String s = "John Vieyra Garza Tepes";
 String[] temp = s.split(" ");
```

En este caso, el array tiene 4 elementos, y puedes obtener sus valores mediante el indice

- `temp[0]` contiene el valor `John`
- `temp[1]` contiene el valor  `Vieyra`
- `temp[2]` contiene el valor `Garza`
- `temp[3]` contiene el valor `Tepes`

Que sucede si intentas obtener el elemento del array con indice 3 del siguiente string:

```
 String s = "John Vieyra";
 String[] temp = s.split(" ");
```

puedes obtener `temp[0]` y `temp[1]` pero el elemento que intentas obtener `temp[3]` no existe, al tratar de obtenerlo obtendrás el siguiente error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Por lo tanto debes asegurar cada linea de tu archivo tenga 4 o más elementos para que no tengas este problema en este punto:

```
 String s = read.nextLine();
 String[] temp = s.split(" ");
```

o [validar primeramente que no se tenga un valor null en el elemento del array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477510/check-if-string-array-element-is-null) en esta linea de código:

```
else if (temp[3].contains(name)) // aqui me marca el error
```