# ¿Como puedo guardar los numeros de un bloc de notas en un array en java?para despues ordenar esos numeros

Tags: java, array, netbeans

```
package vista;

import core.core;

/**
 *
 * @author geovanny9596
 */
public class vista {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //leer un TXT

        core c = new core();
        String s1 = c.leerTxt("C:\\Users\\geovanny9596\\Downloads\\numeros.txt");

        System.out.println(s1);

        String[ ] nombre = new String[s1];


    }


}
```

---

```
package core;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

/**
 *
 * @author geovanny9596
 */
public class core {


     public String leerTxt(String direccion){ //direccion del archivo

        String texto = "";

        try{
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccion));
            String temp = "";
            String bfRead;
            while((bfRead = bf.readLine()) != null){ 
                //haz el ciclo, mientras bfRead tiene datos
                temp = temp + "\n" + bfRead; //guardado el texto del archivo
            }

            texto = temp;

        }catch(Exception e){ 
            System.err.println("No se encontro archivo");
        }

        return texto;

    }
}
```

*El bloc de notas:*

```
1000
60
3
1
50
300
```

Comment: ¿Porque los concatenas en un String si los puedes ir almacenando en un List de Integers directamente?

Comment: Hola. Por convenio, nombra las clases Java con la primera letra en mayúscula.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Como puedo guardar los numeros de un bloc de notas en un array en java?, para despues ordenar esos numeros.

Para recuperar los datos obtenidos y guardarlos en un **array**, podemos trabajar con el método `split(String regex)`, el cual define un separador y recibe como parámetro una expresión regular y nos retorna `String[]`

```
String[] numsStr = s1.split("\\n");
```

---

Y para hacer la **ordenación** tenemos el método sobrecargado `java.util.Arrays.sort(numeros)`, el cual nos hace una ordenación de una forma ascendente

---

También en tu método `leerTxt()` cambia el salto de línea que tienes así: `temp = temp + "\n" + bfRead;`, por esta manera `temp += bfRead+"\n";`, para que te añada antes la cadena y después le añades el salto de línea, no antes como estabas haciendo, sino tendrás problemas a la hora de hacer la conversión de **Strings** a **ints**

```
String[] numsStr = s1.split("\\n");
int[] numeros =  new int[numsStr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numsStr.length; i++) {
     numeros[i] = Integer.parseInt(numsStr[i]);
}
```

---

**Ejemplo:**

```
public class PrincipalCore {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //leer un TXT
        Core c = new Core();
        String s1 = c.leerTxt("C:\\Users\\miusuario\\Desktop\\numeros.txt");
        System.out.println(s1 + "");

        String[] numsStr = s1.split("\\n");
        int[] numeros =  new int[numsStr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < numsStr.length; i++) {
            //if(!numsStr[i].trim().equals(""))
                numeros[i] = Integer.parseInt(numsStr[i]);
        }
        //imprimimos numeros sin ordenar y tal cual los tenemos en nuestro array
        for (int numero : numeros) {
            System.out.print(numero + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("");
        //ordenamos
        java.util.Arrays.sort(numeros);
        for (int numero : numeros) {
            System.out.print(numero + " ");
        }
    }
}


class Core {
    public String leerTxt(String direccion) {
        String texto = "";
        try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccion))) {
            //StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
            String temp = "";
            String bfRead;
            while((bfRead = bf.readLine()) != null){ 
                //haz el ciclo, mientras bfRead tiene datos
                //temp.append(bfRead).append("\n");
                temp += bfRead+"\n"; //guardado el texto del archivo
            }

            texto = temp.toString();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("No se encontró el archivo");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Excepcion " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return texto;
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

---

**Actualización..**

El método **`readLine()`** en el `while`, lo que hará será devolvernos un **String** del contenido leído de una línea o nulo **'null'** si se ha alcanzado el final de la secuencia.

Entendido esto, y sabiendo que en el fichero de texto la información que tenemos son números, podríamos recoger el contenido de cada línea, osea un número y añadirlo a una Lista **'List'** de tipo **Integer**, como bien han comentado.

```
public List leerTxt2(String direccion) {
        List<Integer> listNums = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccion))) {

            String bfRead;
            while((bfRead = bf.readLine()) != null){ 
                listNums.add(Integer.parseInt(bfRead));
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("No se encontró el archivo");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Excepcion " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return listNums;
    }
```

**Y ahora en el main..**

```
//Obtenemos nuestra lista
    List<Integer> lNums = c.leerTxt2("C:/Users/miusuario/Desktop/numeros.txt");

System.out.println("\nImprimimos tal cual están en la lista");
    for (Integer num : lNums) {
        System.out.print(num+ "   ");
    }

    //Ordenamos
    Collections.sort(lNums);
    System.out.println("\nAhora los tenemos ordenados");
    for (Integer num : lNums) {
        System.out.print(num+ "   ");
    }
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método split:

```
String[ ] nombre = s1.split(" ");
```

Comment: Marcada como duplicada: [ https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45846/c%C3%B3mo-separar-un-string-en-java-c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-split ]