# ¿Cómo separar partes de una cadena?

Tags: java, html, string, parsear

Me gustaría pedirles de favor, alguna idea de cómo poder pasar una cadena de String a una tabla de HTML, de la forma más básica. (sin agregar librerías de ser posible).

Tomé una captura en el navegador del String que devuelve toda esa cadena y de esa, lo que va dentro de **[ ]**  es lo que estoy tratando de extraer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De los datos que aparecen en tabla azul, deberían quedar así acomodados como a continuación pero en HTML, ¿cómo podría separlos?

- "errorCorto":"            10.53.37.71 808"
- "errorDetalle":"          10.53.37.71 808"
- "errorTitle":             "Sin clasificar"
- "errorDifs":              "209"
- "errorQuantity":           209

```
    @GetMapping("/get/{galletita}")
    public String getJson(@PathVariable String galletita) {
        String json = "{}";

        logger.info("GALLEEEETAAAAA!: "+galletita);
        json = requestError.obtenerErrores(galletita);

        logger.info("INFO: Se consultó JSON de monitoreo.");
        //json = json.replace("     ", "").replace("    ", "");
        String cad = "";
        if(json.startsWith("{ \"values\": [ {")) {
            //json = json.replace("     ", "").replace("    ", "");

        }
        int inicio = json.indexOf("[");
        int fin = json.lastIndexOf("]");
        cad = json.substring(inicio,fin);
        String partes[] = cad.split("\\,");

        String cad1 = partes[0];

        String cad2 = partes[1];
        String cad3 = partes[2];
        String cad4 = partes[3];
        String cad5 = partes[4];
        json += "<html>";
        json += "<head>";
        json += "</head>";
        json += "<body>";
        json += "<font color =\"#000000\">";
        json += "<table border='2' cellspacing=\"3\" align='center' bgcolor=\"#77BCF5\" bordercolor=\"white\">";
        json += "<tr>";
        json += "<td>" + cad1 + "</td>";
        json += "</tr>";
        json += "<tr>";
        json += "<td>" + cad2 + "</td>";
        json += "</tr>";
        json += "<tr>";
        json += "<td>" + cad3 + "</td>";
        json += "</tr>";
        json += "<tr>";
        json += "<td>" + cad4 + "</td>";
        json += "</tr>";
        json += "<tr>";
        json += "<td>" + cad5 + "</td>";
        json += "</tr>";
        json += "</table>";
        json +="</font color>";
        json += "</body>";
        json += "</html>";


        //mu.sendMail(json, " ");
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: mi recomendacion es que y ya de todas forma lo haces(split(), remplace()), es usar `Regular Expressions` pero Regex mas complejas para extraer lo que desea aqui te dejo un link para que te informes mas sobre ellos [link #1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) [link #2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Cómo separar un String en Java. Cómo utilizar split()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45846/c%c3%b3mo-separar-un-string-en-java-c%c3%b3mo-utilizar-split)

Comment: Ese String es un JSON, ¿por qué no usar alguna librería existente para procesarlo de un modo más sencillo?

Comment: @RuslanLópez realmente no es un Duplicado, dado a que `Split()` no funciona(o es la mejor respuesta/opcion) para este esenario en especifico. de hecho. dado la limitante que indica OP: **(sin agregar librerías de ser posible)** es un problema por que inclusive para hacer Parsing de `json` `Regular Expression` no es la mejor opcion. ver solucion a esta pregunta similar en [StackOverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903283/split-nested-json-in-java-with-regex)