# Contar las veces que aparece cada letra del abecedario en un string java

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un programa que cuente las veces de aparición de cada letra del abecedario (en orden z-a) y que imprima la letra junto a la frecuencia de aparición de esta. El código tiene que obviar cualquier carácter y numero (no solo los que están en el replaceAll), y el texto debería recorrer un string "ABECEDARIO" que es donde se declaran todas las letras del abecedario, pero no he sabido hacerlo así.

> CODIGO

```
public class tasca7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "In a 2017 German study, researchers at Ruhr-University Bochum compared the ability of gamers and non-gamers to remember information from cue cards and then combine that information to predict weather conditions. The video gamers showed greater retention of the cue card knowledge and made better predictions, specially in conditions of uncertainty";
        text = text.toLowerCase();

        text = text.replaceAll("[1234567890.,-]", "");
        char lletrArray[] = text.toCharArray();
        int[] freq = new int[text.length()];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < lletrArray.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lletrArray.length - i - 1; j++) {                                                              
                if (lletrArray[j + 1] > lletrArray[j]) {
                    char aux = lletrArray[j + 1];
                    lletrArray[j + 1] = lletrArray[j];
                    lletrArray[j] = aux;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            freq[i] = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < text.length(); j++) {
                if (lletrArray[i] == lletrArray[j]) {
                    freq[i]++;
                    lletrArray[j] = '0';
                }
            }
        }

        
        for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {
            if (lletrArray[i] != ' ' && lletrArray[i] != '0') {
                System.out.println("La lletra " + lletrArray[i] + " es repeteix " + freq[i] + " vegades.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Por consola deberia salir la lo que en la primera imagen, sin embargo sale lo de la segunda, la diferencia que hay es que no imprime los valores que no estan en el texto i algun valor lo cuenta de más.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `text == ABECEDARI`???? Qué se supone que pretendes con esa igualdad? Primero, los strings en java se deben comparar usando el `.equals(String)`, y segundo... el abecedario nunca va a ser igual a ese texto en inglés, no crees? No entiendo por qué ordenas el array,  y sinceramente parece que hayas copiado y pegado código sin más... porque si eres capaz de hacer un sort manualmente cómo es posible que luego no seas capaz de incrementar el valor de un contador? Veo mucho más difícil order el string que incrementar el contador correcto, para lo que necesitarías usar un `ABECEDARI.indexOf(...)`

Comment: @Benito-B hola, revisa otra vez el codigo por favor, lo he editado con lo que he hecho de nuevo, el anterior codigo era un intento de rehacer el codigo ya que el codigo tenia que obviar cualquier caracter y numero (no solo los que estan en el replaceAll), y el texto deberia recorrer un string "ABECEDARIO" que es donde se declaran todas las letras del abecedario, pero no he sabido hacerlo asi

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Recorrer String con un bucle for y contar las letras, dudas, Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226181/recorrer-string-con-un-bucle-for-y-contar-las-letras-dudas-java)

Comment: Te recomiendo que analices el algoritmo que te piden, hazlo por partes, hasta llegar a la solución. Siempre ten en cuenta el paradigma de "divide y vencerás", es nuestra mejor alternativa para cuando estamos aprendiendo, evita sólo copiar y pegar porque a primera vista pareciera que solo copiaste el código como sugieren en un comentario anterior. Escribe en papel, es una gran manera de llegar a una solución y después de que tengas esto puedes buscar ayuda, inténtalo por ti mismo y verás que tendrás una mejor aceptación en la comunidad para así ayudarte

Comment: Te recomiendo que analices el algoritmo que te piden, hazlo por partes, hasta llegar a la solución. Siempre ten en cuenta el paradigma de "divide y vencerás", es nuestra mejor alternativa para cuando estamos aprendiendo, evita sólo copiar y pegar porque a primera vista pareciera que solo copiaste el código como sugieren en un comentario anterior. Escribe en papel, es una gran manera de llegar a una solución y después de que tengas esto puedes buscar ayuda, inténtalo por ti mismo y verás que tendrás una mejor aceptación en la comunidad para así ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu mismo problema recalca, buscar la frecuencia de cada letra del **abecedario** en la cadena de texto, para lo cual podes crear un array con todas las letras del abecedario e iterar el array `lletrArray`hallando la frecuencia de cada letra del abecedario presente o no en el array ,valga la redundacia iterando el array `abecedario`..podes obtener las letras del abecedario usando como referencia la tabla ascii en donde la letra `a =(char)97` y `z=(char)122` siendo 26 letras en total

```
      text = text.toLowerCase();
            text = text.replaceAll("[ 1234567890.,-]", "");
            char lletrArray[] = text.toCharArray();
         
            char[]abecedario=new char[26];
            int[] freq = new int[abecedario.length];
            int cont=0;
            int k=97;
//agregamos de z hacia a
            for (int i=25;i>=0;i--) {
               abecedario[i]= (char)k;
               k++;
            }
    
            for (int i=0;i<abecedario.length;i++ ) {
            for (int j=0;j<lletrArray.length;j++ ) {
                if(lletrArray[j]==abecedario[i]){
                    cont++; 
                }
             }
//contamos la frecuencia independientemente sila letra del abecedarios esta presento o no en el array lletra
             freq[i]=cont;
             cont=0;  
            }
        
         
         for (int i=0;i<abecedario.length;i++ ) {
             System.out.println("La lletra " + abecedario[i] + " es repeteix " + freq[i] + " vegades.");
         }
```