# como validar un string con un slash en medio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una variable q proviene de un `response` que es igual a "TRUE/FALSE" y la estoy comparando en un if asi :

```
if(  type_q.get(counter).equals("TRUE/FALSE") ){
//do something
}
```

pero no me la reconoce. Si la copio del response sale con  backslash asi:

```
"TRUE\/FALSE"
```

como la puedo validar?  gracias.

Comment: Si imprimes type_q.get(counter) ¿que obtienes?

Comment: TRUE\/FALSE (viene de un array asi:  type":["OPTION","CHECK","TRUE\/FALSE"])

Comment: Si imprimes la respuesta se va a mostrar "\/" pero cuando obtienes ese valor del array no se obtiene "\/", se obtiene únicamente "/", solo asegura que se esta obteniendo el tercer elemento del array, ese debe ser tu problema.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si sabes que es una String que contiene "/", hazle un split , te dividirá la String en un array, en la posición[0] tendrás el true y en la [1] el false, suponiendo que venga "/", sino try catch, comprueba la longitud y si es 0 o peta, hazle el split con "\". puedes intentar también hacer el split con "/" (las 2 barras que te salen) la primera barra que ves es un caracter de escape.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de uso básico:

[Cómo separar un String en Java. Cómo utilizar split()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45846/c%C3%B3mo-separar-un-string-en-java-c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-split)

Comment: con la primera parte ya pude validar, gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Si obtienes el response del JSON se muestra de esta forma tal y como lo indicas:

```
["OPTION","CHECK","TRUE\/FALSE"]
```

Pero si obtienes los valores del json, estos se deben obtener con los valores y **no se obtiene `"TRUE\/FALSE"` si no únicamente `"TRUE/FALSE"`**

```
  JSONObject jsonR = new JSONObject(r);
  JSONArray jsonArr = jsonR.getJSONArray("type");
  System.out.println(type_q.get(0).toString()); //OPTION
  System.out.println(type_q.get(1).toString()); //CHECK
  System.out.println(type_q.get(2).toString()); //TRUE/FALSE
```

por lo tanto **la comparación que realizas debe funcionar sin problema solo asegura que el valor que obtiene sea el del indice 2 que contiene "TRUE/FALSE"**:

```
if( type_q.get(counter).equals("TRUE/FALSE") ){
   //Iguales
}else{
  //No son iguales
}
```