# Como obtener un array de string a partir de una cadena con java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que recibo un List de Integer de otro método.
Estoy recorriendo la lista y guardando los resultado en una cadena String. Lo que quiero es luego convertir esa cadena String en un arreglo String. Lo estoy haciendo de esta forma pero no resulta. No se que estoy haciendo mal!

```
 for (Iterator<Integer> j=ocupada.iterator();j.hasNext();){
                    solucion += j.next().intValue()+".";
                    
                }
                
                String array[]=solucion.split(".");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso es la funcion `split()` debe ser usada pero con el "." escapado es decir:

```
String array[]=solucion.split("\\.");
```

la razon  es que el punto es considerado un [metacaracter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSSHTQ_7.4.0/com.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc_7.4.0/omnibus/wip/common/reference/omn_ref_re_metacharacters.html), revisa esta respuesta:

[**¿Por que no puedo separar texto con split?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/329582/95)