# Cómo convertir un array de tipo char a un array de tipo int

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un programa donde le pido al usuario ingresar una fecha, almaceno los números en un array de tipo char. Lo que quiero hacer es pasar el array de tipo char a uno de tipo int

Tengo este código al momento:

```
public class Fecha {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String f_h;
        String fecha_hora;
        fecha_hora = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la fecha dd/mm/aa y la hora");
        f_h = fecha_hora.replaceAll("/|\\s|:", "");

        char[] caracteres f_h.toCharArray();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible, en este caso tu separador serìa el caràcter "/".

Crea primeramente el array de elementos tipo `String` sin reemplazar el caràcter "/" ya que este serà el separador.

Te sugiero revisar esta respuesta que indica porque debe "escaparse" el caràcter "/" para poder ser usado como separador :

[Cómo separar un String en Java. Cómo utilizar split()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45846/c%C3%B3mo-separar-un-string-en-java-c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-split)

Ahora bien, usa `split()` y crea tu array con elementos tipo `String`:

```
//Crea array tipo String
String[] caracteresString = fecha_hora.split("\\/");
```

#### ¿Como convertir un arreglo de tipo char a un arreglo de tipo int?

A partir de tu array de elementos tipo `String`, crea un array de elementos tipo `Integer` e inserta los valores convirtiendolos de `String` a `Integer` mediante el mètodo `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
 //Crea array tipo Int
 int[] caracteresInt = new int[caracteresString.length];

 //Convierte elementos tipo String del array inicial y los inserta en el array de elementos tipo Integer.
  for(int i = 0 ; i<caracteresString.length ; i++){
        caracteresInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(caracteresString[i]);
  }
```