# Problemas con Split en java

Tags: java

estoy migrando un archivo CVS,haciendo un split mas concatenar, eso sale bien pero en la colummna type en los campos tengo hacer que solo salga el tipo de dato, es decir ahora me figura java.lang.String y necesito que salga solo la palabra String.
estoy haciendo este codigo y cambio algunas cosas pero no me muestra la palabra.Les agradeceria si me podrian guiar .

```
String[] components = record.split(",");
String type[] = components[4].split(",");// Sṕilt de la columna type
String finalType = type[type.length-1];// esta es la parte en donde deberia solo tomar la palabra String
```

El Array componets son las lineas 
el type el campo @TwoDent 
Osea que en las lineas se ve de esta manera :
java.lang.String
java.lang.Integer

Comment: Hola @Hayden, podrias decirnos que te trae con ese codigo ?

Comment: Que es lo que almacena el array "components"? Podrias mostrarlo?

Comment: almacena las lineas

Comment: @Carlosgub me trae lo mismo no hace nada ,es decir , al tener los campos con estos String: Java.lang.String
java.lang.Integer  quiero que me muestre solo String y Integer

Comment: Nunca va a funcionar porque el delimitador debería ser un `.` (punto) y tu lo tienes como una coma. Y si quieres más ayuda, debería de explicar por lo menos, que hace ese código y también especificar en detalle cual es el problema.

Comment: tengo que importar un cvs pero la parte que no me sale es que en la columna type esta el campo java.lang.String y deberia solo estar la palabra string

Comment: @Hayden agrega un ejemplo de tu archivo csv

Answer (score 1):

Hola @Hayden segun lo que comentas te dejo un ejemplo de codigo de como debes de hacerlo:

```
 // Desbes utilizar punto no coma para el separador
 String type[] = components[4].split("\\."); // aqui se aplica un escape al punto para indicar que es el carácter.
 String finalType = type[type.length-1];
 System.out.println(finalType);
```

Algo que debes de tener en cuenta es que el `punto` es un carácter especial de `regex, a diferencia de la coma que no lo es por lo que la coma no es necesario escaparse, con el punto debes de escapar  al caracter de esta forma '\\.' o [.]

Answer (score 1):

El separador debería ser el caracter `.`, pero este caracter es un "metacaracter" por lo tanto debes escapar este caracter al usar el método .split()

```
//Crea array de elementos usando "," como separador.
String[] components = record.split(",");
//Crea array de elementos usando "." como separador. 
String type[] = components[4].split("\\.");
```

Revisa: 
[¿Tienes problemas al usar un caracter como separador?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/45847/95)