# ¿Como filtrar los numeros de un String en java y pasarlos a una lista?

Tags: java

Necesito filtrar los números de un String en java, el formato es el siguiente:

```
String texto = "1,5,10,15,20"
```

y me gustaría poder almacenarlos en una lista pero no encuentro la forma.
por ejemplo, lo que busco es tener dentro de la lista con este formato:

```
lista = [1,5,10,15,20]
```

Lo que he intendado es separarlos dentro de un ciclo for a una lista cada vez que detecta un numero, pero el problema aca es que si el numero es de dos digitos o mas almacena los **digitos por separado** y no completos en una posicion de la lista :(, es decir si tengo un 25 lo almacena asi:

```
[2,5]
```

cuando lo que busco es almacenarlo asi:

```
[25]
```

Comment: has probado con `texto.split(",");`? [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) puedes encontrar información sobre su funcionamiento

Comment: Literalmente una búsqueda en SO poniendo "separar string java" te da la respuesta... por favor usa el buscador antes de abrir una pregunta nueva! Además, uno de los requisitos para preguntar en SO es demostrar una investigación y esfuerzo previos! [Cómo separar un String en Java. Cómo utilizar split()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45846/c%c3%b3mo-separar-un-string-en-java-c%c3%b3mo-utilizar-split)

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

```
String texto = "1,5,10,15,20"

String[] lista= texto.split(",");
String part1 = lista[0]; // == 1
```