# ¿Cómo puedo separa una cadena con "\"?

Tags: java, netbeans

Me encuentro estudiando JAVA con el IDE Netbeans y estoy en la parte de convertir una cadena a varios arreglos.

Leí que con la función .split() se puede realizar pero para caracteres especiales se debe anteponer "\\ + caracter"

Esto es lo que estuve intentando `String[] ruta = cadena.split("\\\") ;` pero me marca un error. De lo que he investigado no me dice si se debe ponerlo andentro de un  `try - catch` o algo similar.

Alguien me puede explicar el cómo es la correcta utilización de la función split() con `\`?

Comment: Y qué error te marca? Por favor agrégalo a la pregunta como texto. Puedes hacer click en [edit] para editar la pregunta

Comment: Agrega el error que te arroja el IDE, así los miembros de la comunidad podemos tener una mejor idea de que te esta sucediendo y ayudarte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el separador es `\`, dado que es un caracter especial en expresiones regulares, para introducirlo -incluso si el procesador no es Java- hay que escaparlo: `\\`.

Pero como en Java también es un caracter especial (de escape) cada una de las diagonales anteriores tiene que escaparse: `\\\\`.

En otras palabras, las primeras dos diagonales son la secuencia de escape de la expresión regular, y las siguientes dos diagonales son el caracter escapado de la expresión regular.

```
String[] ruta = cadena.split("\\\\");
```

Answer (score 1):

El uso de la función split es muy simple. Tal cual como lo tienes va a dividir la cadena ingresada donde encuentre "\\\" la primera vez.
Acá te dejo una pregunta similar con bastantes aportes:
[Cómo separar un String en Java. Cómo utilizar split()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45846/c%C3%B3mo-separar-un-string-en-java-c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-split) .

Espero que puedas aclarar tus dudas. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, si entendí como funciona la función, lo que pasa es que no me deja poner entre comillas y según lo que leí pero si me dejo mediante ``` String separador = Pattern.quote("\\");```

Comment: En el link que te adjunte habla sobre eso. Se llaman "metacaracteres" y explica como manejarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución para poder buscar el caracter especial fue creando una variable string y utilizando el `pattern.quote()` de tal modo:

`String separador = Pattern.quote("\\");`

luego pude realizar el split() normalmente y así quedo por el momento hasta poder encontrar una solución para poder ingresar el caracter especial directamente en la función split y no tener que crear una variable más:

`String[] ruta = cadena.split(separador);`